# Outofmemoryexception in binding datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a outofmemoryexception . I am trying to retrieve from CRM over 7000 accounts and stock into the list of contratvuemodele. This list will be add to the observablecollection of contratvuemodele and bind to datagrid.
But my application do not work. 
here is my codes:

code xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="GestionDeContrats_Offres_ClientsGUI.VueModele.UserControlGestionContrat"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             x:Name="GestionContrat"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GestionDeContrats_Offres_ClientsGUI.VueModele"
             d:DesignHeight="300"  >
   <!-- <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:GestionDeContratVueModele  />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    -->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="320"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox Name="searchtexbox" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="/GestionDeContrats_Offres_ClientsGUI;component/Images/16_find.gif" />
        </Grid>
        <ToolBar Grid.Row="1" Name="toolbarcontrat">
            <Button    Name="btNewContrat"  Click="btNewContrat_Click">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Source="/GestionDeContrats_Offres_ClientsGUI;component/Images/plusvert.jpg" />
                    <Label Content="Nouveau" Grid.Column="1"/>

                </Grid>
            </Button>

            <Button    Name="btCopierContrat" >
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Source="/GestionDeContrats_Offres_ClientsGUI;component/Images/editcopy.png" />
                    <Label Content="Copier" Grid.Column="1"/>

                </Grid>
            </Button>
            <Button    Name="btSupprimerContrat" >
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Source="/GestionDeContrats_Offres_ClientsGUI;component/Images/delgreen16.jpg" />
                    <Label Content="Supprimer" Grid.Column="1"/>
                </Grid>
            </Button>
            <Button    Name="btModifierContrat" >
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Source="/GestionDeContrats_Offres_ClientsGUI;component/Images/ico_18_4207.gif" />
                    <Label Content="Modifier" Grid.Column="1"/>
                </Grid>
            </Button>

        </ToolBar>

        <DataGrid Name="listViewContrat" Grid.Row="2" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Lescontrats, Mode=OneWay}"  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="True" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserSortColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Nom du contrat" >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=NOMDUCONTRAT, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Date de début" >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DATEDEDEBUT, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Date de fin"  >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DATEDEFIN, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Statut" >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LESTATUT,Mode=OneWay}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Statut avant" >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text=""/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Margin="2" Content=""/>
            <Button Content="Suivant" Name="btNext" Margin="2" />
            <Button Content="Précédent" Name="btPrevious" Margin="2"  />


        </StackPanel>



    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

code cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using GestionDeContrats_Offres_ClientsGUI.VueModele;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.ComponentModel;
using GestionDeContrats_Offres_Clients.GestionOffres;
using GestionDeContrats_Offres_Clients.GestionContrats;
using System.Windows.Input;
using GestionDeContrats_Offres_Clients.GestionModele;
using GestionDeContrats_Offres_ClientsGUI.crm;
using System.Data;

namespace GestionDeContrats_Offres_ClientsGUI.VueModele
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
   public class GestionDeContratVueModele : VueModeleBase
    {

        private readonly ObservableCollection<ContratVueModele> contrats;
        private readonly ICollectionView collectionView;
        //private readonly PagingCollectionView pagingView;
        private GestionDeContrat gestiondecontrat;
        private ICommand activerContratCommand;
        private ICommand supprimerContratCommand;
        private ICommand modifierContratCommand;
        private ICommand copierContratCommand;
        private ICommand creerContratCommand;
        private ICommand nextPageCommand;
        private ICommand previousPageCommand;
        private int currentpage;



       /// <summary>
       /// Constructeur de la classe
       /// GestionDeContratVueModele 
       /// </summary>
        public GestionDeContratVueModele() {


            try
            {

                this.gestiondecontrat = new GestionDeContrat();

                List<ContratVueModele> maliste = new List<ContratVueModele>(10000);
                //maliste.Clear();

                // this.contrats.Clear();

                foreach (contract contrat in this.gestiondecontrat.ListeDeContrat())
                {
                    // this.contrats.Add(new ContratVueModele());
                    maliste.Add(new ContratVueModele() { NOMDUCONTRAT = contrat.title, DATEDEDEBUT = contrat.activeon.Value, DATEDEFIN = contrat.expireson.Value, LESTATUT = contrat.statecode.formattedvalue, LESTATUTAVANT = contrat.access_etatavant.name });
                    // this.contrats.Add(new ContratVueModele() { NOMDUCONTRAT = contrat.title, DATEDEDEBUT = contrat.activeon.Value, DATEDEFIN = contrat.expireson.Value, LESTATUT = contrat.statecode.formattedvalue,LESTATUTAVANT=contrat.access_etatavant.name });


                }
                this.contrats = new ObservableCollection<ContratVueModele>(maliste);

                this.collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.contrats);
                if (this.collectionView == null)
                    throw new NullReferenceException("collectionView");

                // this.collectionView.CurrentChanged += new EventHandler(collectionView_CurrentChanged);

                // this.pagingView = new PagingCollectionView(this.contrats, 15);

                //if (this.pagingView == null)
                //throw new NullReferenceException("pagingView");
                //this.currentpage = this.pagingView.CurrentPage;
                //this.pagingView.CurrentChanged += new EventHandler(pagingView_CurrentChanged);
            }
            catch (System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException soapEx)
            {

                soapEx.Detail.OuterXml.ToString();

            }
            catch (System.OutOfMemoryException memoryException)
            {

                memoryException.InnerException.ToString();

            }
            catch (System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException targetex) {


                targetex.InnerException.ToString();
            }

        }

       /// <summary>
       /// 
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="sender"></param>
       /// <param name="e"></param>
        //void pagingView_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        //{
        //    OnPropertyChanged("SelectedContrat");
        //    Dispose();
        //    //throw new NotImplementedException();
        //}

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gestiondecontrat"></param>
        public GestionDeContratVueModele(GestionDeContrat gestiondecontrat)
        {

            this.gestiondecontrat = gestiondecontrat;


            this.contrats = new ObservableCollection<ContratVueModele>();

            foreach (contract contrat in this.gestiondecontrat.ListeDeContrat())
            {

                this.contrats.Add(new ContratVueModele() { NOMDUCONTRAT=contrat.title,DATEDEDEBUT=contrat.activeon.Value, DATEDEFIN=contrat.expireson.Value,LESTATUT=contrat.statecode.formattedvalue});


            }
            this.collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.contrats);
            if (this.collectionView == null)
                throw new NullReferenceException("collectionView");

            this.collectionView.CurrentChanged += new EventHandler(collectionView_CurrentChanged);

        }


       /// <summary>
       /// 
       /// </summary>
        public ICommand ActiverContratCommand {

            get
            {

                if (this.activerContratCommand == null)
                    this.activerContratCommand = new CommandeDeRelais(() => this.ActiverContrat(), () => this.CanActiverContrat());
                return this.activerContratCommand;
            }

        }

       /// <summary>
       /// 
       /// </summary>
        public ICommand CopierContratCommand
        {

            get
            {

                if (this.copierContratCommand == null)
                    this.copierContratCommand = new CommandeDeRelais(() => this.CopierContrat(), () => this.CanCopierContrat());
                return this.copierContratCommand;
            }

        }

       /// <summary>
       /// 
       /// </summary>
       /// <returns></returns>
        private bool CanCopierContrat()
        {

            return true;
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
       /// <summary>
       /// 
       /// </summary>
        private void CopierContrat()
        {
            this.gestiondecontrat.copier();
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

       /// <summary>
       /// 
       /// </summary>

        //public ICommand NextPageCommand {

        //    get {

        //        if(this.nextPageCommand==null)
        //            this.nextPageCommand = new CommandeDeRelais(() => this.NextPage(), () => this.CanNextPage());
        //        return nextPageCommand;

        //    }


        //}
       /// <summary>
       /// 
       /// </summary>
        //private void NextPage() {

        //    this.pagingView.MoveToNextPage();

        //}
       /// <summary>
       /// 
       /// </summary>
       /// <returns></returns>
        //private bool CanNextPage() {


        //    return this.pagingView.PageCount > 1;//true; //Todo à reimplementer correctement
        //}


       /// <summary>
       /// Permet de gérer le passage à la page précedente
       /// </summary>
        //private void PreviousPage()
        //{

        //    this.pagingView.MoveToPreviousPage();

        //}

       /// <summary>
        /// Vérifie si on peut passer à la page précédente
       /// </summary>
       /// <returns>un booléen qui nous dit si on peut passer à la commande précédente</returns>
        //private bool CanPreviousPage()
        //{


        //    return this.pagingView.MoveCurrentToPrevious();//true; //Todo à reimplementer correctement
        //}



       /// <summary>
       /// Lecteur qui prend en charge la commande associée au bouton 
       /// </summary>
        //public ICommand PreviousPageCommand
        //{

        //    get
        //    {
        //        if (this.previousPageCommand==null)
        //            this.previousPageCommand = new CommandeDeRelais(() => this.PreviousPage(), () => this.CanPreviousPage());
        //        return previousPageCommand;

        //    }


        //}

       /// <summary>
       /// Lecteur de la page courante
       /// </summary>

        public int CURRENTPAGE {

            get {

               return this.currentpage;
            }

        }

       /// <summary>
       /// Lecteur qui prend en charge la Commande qui s'exécute quand on appuie sur le bouton créer
       /// ce bouton sera lié à cette propriété
       /// </summary>
        public ICommand CreerContratCommand {

            get
            {

                if (this.creerContratCommand == null)
                    this.creerContratCommand = new CommandeDeRelais(() => this.CreerContrat(), () => this.CanCreerContrat());
                return this.creerContratCommand;
            }

        }

       /// <summary>
       /// Lecteur sur la commande supprimer le contrat
       /// </summary>
        public ICommand SupprimerContratCommand {

            get {

                if (this.supprimerContratCommand == null)
                    this.supprimerContratCommand = new CommandeDeRelais(() => this.SupprimerContrat(), () => this.CanSupprimerContrat());
                return this.supprimerContratCommand;

            }


        }
       /// <summary>
       /// 
       /// </summary>
        public ICommand ModifierContratCommand {

            get {
                if (this.modifierContratCommand == null)
                    this.modifierContratCommand = new CommandeDeRelais(() => this.ModifierContrat(), () => this.CanModifierContrat());
                return this.modifierContratCommand;

            }

        }

                /// <summary>
        /// Propriété permettant de manipuler la 
        ///Vue Modèle de la liste des contrats
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<ContratVueModele> Lescontrats
        {

            get
            {

                return this.contrats;
            }


        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Propriété permettant de manipuler la vue modèle
        /// de selection du contrat
        /// </summary>
        public ContratVueModele SelectedContrat
        {
            get
            {

                return this.collectionView.CurrentItem as ContratVueModele;

            }

        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Propriété permettant manipuler la vue modèle qui vérifie si 
        /// que la vue est vide
        /// </summary>
        public bool SearchContainsNoMatch
        {

            get
            {


                return this.collectionView.IsEmpty;
            }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Propriété permettant manipuler la vue modèle 
        /// de recherche du contrat en fonction du nom ou du statut
        /// </summary>
        public string RechercheText
        {

            set
            {

                this.collectionView.Filter = (item) =>
                    {

                        if (item as ContratVueModele == null)
                            return false;

                        ContratVueModele contratvueModele = (ContratVueModele)item;
                        if (contratvueModele.NOMDUCONTRAT.Contains(value) || contratvueModele.LESTATUT.Contains(value))
                            return true;
                        return false;
                    };
                this.OnPropertyChanged("SearchContainsNoMatch");
            }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handler pour la sélection du contrat
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        public void collectionView_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedContrat");
            //Dispose();
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        private void CreerContrat() {

            try
            {
                 this.gestiondecontrat.creer();
                 foreach (contract contrat in this.gestiondecontrat.ListeDeContrat())
                 {

                     this.contrats.Add(new ContratVueModele() { NOMDUCONTRAT=contrat.title, DATEDEDEBUT=contrat.activeon.Value, DATEDEFIN=contrat.expireson.Value, ADRESSE=contrat.serviceaddress.name, NET=contrat.netprice.Value});


                 }

            }
            catch(Exception creerEx){

                creerEx.Message.ToString();

            }

        }


        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private bool CanCreerContrat() {

            return true;

        }
       /// <summary>
       /// 
       /// </summary>
        private void ActiverContrat()
        {

            try
            {
                this.gestiondecontrat.ActiverContrat(this.SelectedContrat.CONTRAT);


            }
            catch (Exception activerEx)
            {

                activerEx.Message.ToString();

            }

        }
       /// <summary>
       /// 
       /// </summary>
       /// <returns></returns>
        private bool CanActiverContrat()
        {

            return this.SelectedContrat.LESTATUT != "Annulé";

        }

       /// <summary>
       /// 
       /// </summary>
        private void SupprimerContrat()
        {

            try
            {
                this.gestiondecontrat.supprimer();
                this.contrats.Remove(new ContratVueModele(this.SelectedContrat.CONTRAT));
            }
            catch (Exception supprimerEx)
            {

                supprimerEx.Message.ToString();

            }

        }

       /// <summary>
       /// 
       /// </summary>
       /// <returns></returns>
        private bool CanSupprimerContrat()
        {

            return this.contrats.Count>0;//true;

        }

       /// <summary>
       /// 
       /// </summary>
        private void ModifierContrat() {


            this.gestiondecontrat.modifier();


        }
       /// <summary>
       /// 
       /// </summary>
       /// <returns></returns>
        private bool CanModifierContrat() {


            return this.SelectedContrat != null;

        }

       /// <summary>
       /// 
       /// </summary>
        private void OuvrirDocumentContrat()
        {

            try
            {
               // Contrat newContrat = this.gestiondecontrat.CreerContrat(new Contrat(new ModeleDeContrat()));
                //this.contrats.Add(new ContratVueModele(newContrat));
            }
            catch (Exception OuvrirDocumentContratEx)
            {

                OuvrirDocumentContratEx.Message.ToString();

            }

        }


       /// <summary>
       /// 
       /// </summary>
       /// <returns></returns>
        private bool CanOuvrirDocumentContrat()
        {

            return true;

        }



    }
}
```

code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace GestionDeContrats_Offres_ClientsGUI.VueModele
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logique d'interaction pour UserControlGestionContrat.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserControlGestionContrat : UserControl
    {
        private readonly GestionDeContratVueModele vuemodelecontrat;

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public UserControlGestionContrat()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.vuemodelecontrat = new GestionDeContratVueModele();
            this.DataContext = this.vuemodelecontrat;
        }
    }     
}
```

In my MainWindow.xaml i just integrate all usercontrol

Thanks

Best regards

Comment: What is your actual question here?

Comment: i need to know how to resolve this outofmemoryException. i can't see nothing in my datagrid. my application stops throw the outofmemoryexception. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried loading less data? This is just a wild guess, but could it be that you are indeed loading too much data into memory for the system to handle...?

Comment: Thanks Jens H. I am trying to load over 7000 accounts. for less it is ok, but for this list of items it don't work . I want to know how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

i resolved a part of this problem by using listview, by making some changes on design. i made somes methods and called this in my constructor, now adding on list is making into these methods. I also change binding mode.

Now i have another problem.
When i run my solution on visual studio it takes a lot of time more then half an hour.it consumes many resources. and it is not finished correctly.